# Forum should just show up in groups

Tags: organic-groups

I would like to have, on my Drupal 8 site, a forum that can be visited only by the members of the group XY; all the other users should not see the forum.

In the permissions I can't find one for viewing the content of the forum.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with the module [Forum Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/forum_access).

> This module changes your forum administration page to allow you to set
>   forums private. You can control what user roles can view, edit,
>   delete, and post to each forum. You can also give each forum a list of
>   users who have administrative access on that forum (AKA moderators).